# getting the profile image from twitter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter, asihttprequest

```
{
    NSString *postUrl =  @"http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image.json ";
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc]
                                   initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postUrl]];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization"
                        value:[oAuth oAuthHeaderForMethod:@"GET"
                                                   andUrl:postUrl
                                                andParams:nil]];
    [request setPostValue: userName forKey:@"screen_name"]; 
    [request startSynchronous];
}
```

In my application I want to show the twitter profile image of the user who uses this application which is for uploading images to twitter. How can I retrieve the profile image of the user? I am using the url  http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/:screen_name.format for this. And ASIHTTP GET method.But it fails. Can anyone help me to do this? The code i am using is given above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong URL, just replace the :screen_name.format to the the users screen name and image format:

```
NSString *imageUrl =  @"http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/rckoenes.png";
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc]
                               initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];
[request startSynchronous];
```

Comment: rckoenes,I have replaced the url.but i am getting the response as "Status posted. HTTP result code: 200
2011-11-11 12:02:13.684 PlainOAuth[393:b303] Response string: ÿØÿà"

Comment: You can use the URL above without any login, it will redirect to to the correct image URL, just copy past the url in your browser you will see my use icon. Just fire of the ASIHTTPRequest garb the NSDate and init image with that data.

Comment: @ValentinSolina but when this question was asked it was.

Comment: No, this was the answer to the question asked. If you would always update your answer to all the API changes every where it would be come a full time job.